# How to add a search button action in autocomplete search

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, blogger

I'm having problem in one issue. Blogger autocomplete search. I'm novice in programming. I want to add a button in the bottom which will work as a search submit / action button.

Here's my code:

```
    <style type="text/css">
  #searchForm {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
  }
  #searchForm input {
    background: transparent;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 27px;
    text-indent: 14px;
    width: 90%;
    color: #212121;
    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    border-right: none;
    border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
    outline: 0;
  }
  #searchForm input:hover,
  #searchForm button:hover {
    border: 1px solid #b9b9b9;
    border-top: 1px solid #a0a0a0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  }
  #searchForm button {
    width: 60px;
    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
    background: rgb(230, 230, 230);
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    outline: 0;
    line-height: 27px;
  }
  #searchForm button svg {
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 21px;
    height: 21px;
  }
  .results {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    width: 90%;
    min-width: 320px;
    border-top: unset;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  }
  .results li {
    line-height: 15px;
    list-style: none;
  }
  .results li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 15px;
    color: #212121;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 30px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }
  .results li:hover {
    background: rgb(230, 230, 230);
  }
  .hidden {
    display: none !important;
  }

  .expanded_result {
    display: none;
  }
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="searchForm" action="/search">
  <input autocomplete="off" name="q" placeholder="Search" value="" />
</form>

<ul id="rslt" class="results hidden"></ul>

<button class="clear-text hidden">×</button>

<script>
  //<![CDATA[
  $(window).on("load", function () {
    $("#searchForm input").on("keyup", function (e) {
      var textinput = $(this).val();

      if (textinput) {
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "https://www.soratemplates.com/feeds/posts/summary",
          data: {
            alt: "json",
            q: textinput,
          },
          dataType: "jsonp",
          success: function (data) {
            $(".results,.clear-text").removeClass("hidden");
            $(".results").empty();
            let seeMoreArr = [];
            function mk_list_dom(postUrl, postTitle) {
              return (
                "<li><a href=" +
                postUrl +
                ' title="' +
                postTitle +
                '">' +
                postTitle +
                "</li>"
              );
            }

            if (data.feed.entry) {
              for (var i = 0; i < data.feed.entry.length; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < data.feed.entry[i].link.length; j++) {
                  if (data.feed.entry[i].link[j].rel == "alternate") {
                    var postUrl = data.feed.entry[i].link[j].href;
                    break;
                  }
                }

                var postTitle = data.feed.entry[i].title.$t;

                i < 10 && $(".results").append(mk_list_dom(postUrl, 

postTitle));
                    

i > 9 && seeMoreArr.push({ postUrl, postTitle });
              }
              
              
              /*

              data.feed.entry.length > 9 &&
                $(".results").append(
                  '<div class="expand_"> <div class="expanded_result"></div> <button class="expand_btn">see more</button></div>'
                ),
                

                seeMoreArr.forEach(({ postUrl, postTitle }) => {
                  $(".expanded_result").append(mk_list_dom(postUrl, postTitle));
                }),
                
                
                $(".expand_btn").on("click", (e) => {
                  $(".expanded_result").toggle();

                  $(e.target).text(function (i, text) {
                    return text === "see more" ? "see less" : "see more";
                  });
                  
                });
               
               */
                
                
            } else {
              $(".results").append(
                "<div> No results </div>"
              );
            }

            data.feed.entry
              ? $(".results").append(
                  "<div>found result: " + data.feed.entry.length + "</div>"
                )
              : $(".results").append("<div>found result: 0</div>");
          },
        });
      } else {
        $(".results,.clear-text").addClass("hidden");
      }
    });

    $(".clear-text").click(function () {
      $("#searchForm input").val("");
      $(".results,.clear-text").addClass("hidden");
      $(".results").empty();
    });
  });
  //]]>
</script>
```

I want to add a button at the bottom of result div or section, which Will work as submit / search button. By clicking people can go to search results.

If anyone know, please help me.

Comment: Alhamdulillah.... I found the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show the code with snippets so people can better understand your question.

As for your question, the code that adds a button is already available where you shared it. It was a script that memorized after 9 recordings and added the results when you said show more. You put it in the comment line. With a small change, you can update it as a button that leads to the page you want as follows.

```js
  //<![CDATA[
  $(window).on("load", function () {
    $("#searchForm input").on("keyup", function (e) {
      var textinput = $(this).val();

      if (textinput) {
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "https://www.ilmulislam.com/feeds/posts/summary",
          data: {
            alt: "json",
            q: textinput,
          },
          dataType: "jsonp",
          success: function (data) {
            $(".results,.clear-text").removeClass("hidden");
            $(".results").empty();
            let seeMoreArr = [];
            function mk_list_dom(postUrl, postTitle) {
              return (
                "<li><a href=" +
                postUrl +
                ' title="' +
                postTitle +
                '">' +
                postTitle +
                "</li>"
              );
            }

            if (data.feed.entry) {
              for (var i = 0; i < data.feed.entry.length; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < data.feed.entry[i].link.length; j++) {
                  if (data.feed.entry[i].link[j].rel == "alternate") {
                    var postUrl = data.feed.entry[i].link[j].href;
                    break;
                  }
                }

                var postTitle = data.feed.entry[i].title.$t;

                if (i < 10) {
                  $(".results").append(mk_list_dom(postUrl, postTitle))
                } else {
                  seeMoreArr.push({ postUrl, postTitle })
                }
        
              }
              
              if (data.feed.entry.length > 1){
                $(".results").append(
                  '<div class="expand_"> <div class="expanded_result"></div> <button class="expand_btn">see all</button</div>'
                );
              }
              
              $(".expand_btn").on("click", (e) => {
                  alert("redirect to : www.google.com/search?q=" + textinput)
               });
              
           
              /*

              data.feed.entry.length > 9 &&
                $(".results").append(
                  '<div class="expand_"> <div class="expanded_result"></div> <button class="expand_btn">see more</button></div>'
                ),
                

                seeMoreArr.forEach(({ postUrl, postTitle }) => {
                  $(".expanded_result").append(mk_list_dom(postUrl, postTitle));
                }),
                
                
                $(".expand_btn").on("click", (e) => {
                  $(".expanded_result").toggle();

                  $(e.target).text(function (i, text) {
                    return text === "see more" ? "see less" : "see more";
                  });
                  
                });
               
               */
                
                
            } else {
              $(".results").append(
                "<div> No results </div>"
              );
            }

            data.feed.entry
              ? $(".results").append(
                  "<div>found result: " + data.feed.entry.length + "</div>"
                )
              : $(".results").append("<div>found result: 0</div>");
          },
        });
      } else {
        $(".results,.clear-text").addClass("hidden");
      }
    });

    $(".clear-text").click(function () {
      $("#searchForm input").val("");
      $(".results,.clear-text").addClass("hidden");
      $(".results").empty();
    });
  });
  //]]>
```

```css
  #searchForm {
    display: inline-flex;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #searchForm input {
    background: transparent;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 27px;
    text-indent: 14px;
    width: 90%;
    color: #212121;
    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    border-right: none;
    border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
    outline: 0;
  }
  #searchForm input:hover,
  #searchForm button:hover {
    border: 1px solid #b9b9b9;
    border-top: 1px solid #a0a0a0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  }
  #searchForm button {
    width: 10%;
    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
    background: rgb(230, 230, 230);
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: 0;
    line-height: 27px;
  }
  #searchForm button svg {
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 21px;
    height: 21px;
  }
  .results {
    position: absolute;
    margin:0;
     padding-left: 0;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: unset;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  }
  .results li {
    line-height: 15px;
    list-style: none;
  }
  .results li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 15px;
    color: #212121;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 30px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }
  .results li:hover {
    background: rgb(230, 230, 230);
  }
  .hidden {
    display: none !important;
  }

  .expanded_result {
    display: none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="position:absolute;top:50px;width:500px;">

<form id="searchForm" action="/search">
  <input autocomplete="off" name="q" placeholder="Search" value="" />
  <button class="clear-text hidden">×</button>
</form>

<ul id="rslt" class="results hidden"></ul>
</div>
```